# Some weird propositions in probability

Tags: probability

I have met some weird statements in probability that I am not sure whether they are  true or false. For all event space A:

$A\subset\Omega$ and $\Omega\subset A$ ($\Omega$ is the sample space).

This is really weird, because that would mean $A=\Omega$. In my opinion, it must be

$A\subset\Omega$ and $\emptyset\subset A$ ($\emptyset$ represents impossible events)

Comment: If $\Omega$ is the sample space, then an event must satisfy $A \subset \Omega$. Both $\Omega$ and $\emptyset$ are events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second conclusion, $\emptyset \subset A \subset \Omega$, is correct. Every set has the empty set as a subset, and every event is a subset of the sample space.

If you found this in a textbook, try looking up its errata online. You can usually find them for free on the textbook's website.

Comment: You mean my opinion is right?

Comment: the second one?

Comment: Which is the second one?

Comment: Can anyone tell me which is the second one?

Comment: I've edited my answer to be a bit less cryptic